# UILabel in a Prototype Cell is not updated from code

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, uilabel

I have 2 `UILabel`s in a Prototype Cell designed in the Storyboard. Both have their designated `tag` number (1000 and 1001). When I write the `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method it seems that one of the labels is receiving the relevant `NSString` and the other one doesn't.

Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {           

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ContentCell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    ContentObject * contentObject =  [contentPackageManager.contentObjectsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
//contentPackageManager is a class that holds an NSArray of ContentObjects (it does a few other things, but they are not relevant for this method...)
//ContentObject is a class that holds several attributs such as: NSString*name, NSString*type, etc...

    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
    nameLabel.text = contentObject.name; //this line works OK

    UILabel * typeLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1001]; 
    typeLabel.text = contentObject.contentType; //this is the PROBLEMATIC one - no effect on the actual UILabel

    return cell;           
}
```

Is anyone familiar with this issue?

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if  `contentObject.contentType` is not null.

Comment: contentObject.contentType is not NULL (I NSLogged it) while typeLabel.text is NULL.